Equivalent definition for bundle orientability.
We know there are several equivalent definition for orientability of manifolds(see Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds):

Existence of a choice of orientation at each point $p\in M$, such that locally there is a continuous(or smooth) frame that consistent with this orientation.
Existence of an atlas such that transition function has positive Jacobian.
Existence of a global non-vanishing top form

For a vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$ orientation, the definition is

An orientation at every point $p\in M$, such that there exists local sections that compatible with this orientation.
Existence of trivaliztions such that transistion map has positive Jacobian.

Are there condition 3. like the case of a manifold that involves differential forms?My guess is:
Bundle orientable iff there is a nonvanishing global form $\tau$ such that $\tau_{(p,0)}$ lies in kernel of $\Omega_p(E)\to \Omega_p(M)$.
What about the case of fiber bundle?
Any reference is welcome

See this PhySE answer of mine for more details about various ways of saying a vector bundle is orientable.
